# VSCode remote Jupyter Notebook - Open an existing notebook in a specific folder on Jupyter Notebook remote server

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I can connect to a remote Jupyter Notebook server with a token from VSCode through the "Python: Specify Jupyter server URI" command from the Command Palette.

However, I didn't find a way to do 2 things:

1. Open an existing Notebook on the remote Jupyter Notebook server.
2. Specify a folder to connect to, where my existing notebook resides in the remote server.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Hi,  How did you connect?  I am trying to find the value of endpoint url from AWS console, but am unsuccessful.  If you could let me know, how you set it, that would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, VSCode doesn't support this functionality. See this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8161